# Convert a string into a mathematical expressinon [arduino]

Tags: winforms, arduino

I have a Windows forms app sending user-written mathematical expressions/functions over the serial port to an arduino.
My question is if there is any way to turn these strings into usable code?

For example, if I receive the string "x*x" is there any way to use this string as a function in my code and loop thru its values. In python you use something called lambda I believe, is there maybe something similar in arduino? I was unable to find anything while googling :/

Or would it perhaps be wiser to loop thru the values in my windows forms app and send each value thru the serial port? To me, that just sounds terribly innefficient tho.

Sorry in advance for my bad coding knowledge this is just for a high school project and it by no means has to be perfect.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do here. When you saying use it as a function, you mean evaluate an arbitrary expression with constants(e.g. "5 + 7 * 3 / 4")? Or are you trying to solve for `x` in some equation?

Comment: This isn't a free project design service.

Comment: Maybe see this question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31466/eval-function-for-arduino -- it references a **TinyExpr** library at https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr